# d3.queue never triggering .await function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've run into a problem using [d3-queue](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue). This is my code:

```
var dataQueue = d3.queue();
dataQueue.defer(collectData,ISBNs,locations)
     .await(processData);
```

Where `collectData` is a function that does several API calls (a large number of them to the Google Books API).

Now the problem is that the `processData` function is never called. I know for a fact that the `collectData` function runs properly, since I put a print statement just before the return statement, along with several other print statements along the way.

Comment: Could you provide the relevant parts of `collectData()`? Does it properly invoke the callback passed to it as the last argument? You wrote about a return statement, whereas the task callback is not supposed to explicitly return anything, though.

Comment: @altocumulus Thanks for the help, you've made me realise that I should call a callback function instead of simply returning! 

I fixed it by adding a callback argument to my `collectData` function and calling this callback instead of the return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing your data correctly between the deferred task `collectData` and the final `processData`. The documentation has it as follows (emphasis mine):

> [#](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue#queue_defer) queue.**defer**(*task*[, *arguments…*]) [<>](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue/blob/master/src/queue.js#L20)
>
> Adds the specified asynchronous *task* callback to the queue, with any optional arguments. The *task* is a function that will be called when the task should start. It is passed the specified optional *arguments* and an **additional *callback* as the last argument**; **the callback must be invoked by the task when it finishes**. The task must invoke the callback with two arguments: the *error*, if any, and the *result* of the task.

Thus, to pass the result of the deferred task to the function `processData`, your function `collectData()` has to be something like this:

```
function collectData(ISBNs, locations, callback) {
  var error = null;  // The error, if any
  var data = { };    // The actual data to pass on
  // ...collect your data...

  // Pass the collected data (and the error) by invoking the callback.
  callback(error, data);
}
```